# Remove stdc++ library dependency

Tags: c++, linker, autotools

I have a library which is written in C++ but isn't using the stdc++ library because it is not available in some platforms.

However, I still have the stdc++ library dependency in my libsmartrest.la which makes all libraries depending on this library fail to link.

Here is my configure.ac and Makefile.am:

```
# Process this file with autoreconf to produce a configure script.
# See http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/building_libraries/building_libraries for introduction.

AC_INIT([Cumulocity SmartREST C++ Library], [1.0.0], [support@cumulocity.com], [libsmartrest], [https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-c/])

# Must come before AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE.
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

# These are automake arguments, not compiler arguments.
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall foreign subdir-objects])

AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_AR([act-if-fail])
LT_INIT

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strerror])
AC_FUNC_MALLOC

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])

AC_OUTPUT

dnl Print configuration summary

cat <<EOF
=====================

$PACKAGE_NAME (version $PACKAGE_VERSION) is now configured.
You can now build, test and install $PACKAGE_NAME using the Makefile, by calling

\$ make
\$ make check    # Optional
\$ make install

EOF
```

Makefile.am:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsmartrest.la

libsmartrest_la_SOURCES = \
    src/Aggregator.cpp\
    src/CharValue.cpp\
    src/FloatValue.cpp\
    src/IntegerValue.cpp\
    src/NullValue.cpp\
    src/Parser.cpp\
    src/ParsedRecord.cpp\
    src/ParsedValue.cpp\
    src/SmartRest.cpp\
    src/Record.cpp\
    src/ComposedRecord.cpp\
    src/StaticData.cpp
libsmartrest_la_CXXFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated
libsmartrest_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 1:0:0

libsmartrest_hdir = $(includedir)/smartrest
libsmartrest_h_HEADERS = \
    src/AbstractClient.h\
    src/AbstractDataSink.h\
    src/AbstractDataSource.h\
    src/Aggregator.h\
    src/CharValue.h\
    src/DataGenerator.h\
    src/FloatValue.h\
    src/IntegerValue.h\
    src/NullValue.h\
    src/Parser.h\
    src/ParsedRecord.h\
    src/ParsedValue.h\
    src/SmartRest.h\
    src/Record.h\
    src/ComposedRecord.h\
    src/StaticData.h\
    src/Value.h

EXTRA_DIST = README \
        LICENSE

TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS)
check_PROGRAMS = values parser client
values_SOURCES = \
    test/values/mainvalues.cpp\
    test/mock/BufferedDataSink.cpp\
    test/values/CharValueTest.cpp\
    test/values/ParsedValueTest.cpp\
    test/values/AggregatorTest.cpp\
    test/values/IntegerValueTest.cpp\
    test/values/FloatValueTest.cpp\
    test/values/ComposedRecordTest.cpp
values_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -I$(srcdir)/src
values_LDADD = -lsmartrest
parser_SOURCES = \
    test/parser/mainparser.cpp\
    test/mock/BufferedDataSource.cpp\
    test/parser/ParserTest.cpp
parser_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -I$(srcdir)/src
parser_LDADD = -lsmartrest
client_SOURCES = \
    test/client/mainclient.cpp\
    test/client/SmartRestTest.cpp\
    test/mock/BufferedDataSource.cpp\
    test/mock/BufferedDataSink.cpp\
    test/mock/MockClient.cpp\
    test/mock/MockSmartRest.cpp
client_CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -I$(srcdir)/src
client_LDADD = -lsmartrest
```

The compilation on my desktop system goes well. However, I get this in my .la file:

```
dependency_libs=' -L/home/ec2-user/SDK_Bovine_ntc_6200/libstage/lib /home/mattf/src/buildbot/sandbox/slave/release_ntc_6200/build/Bovine_src/staging_sdk/SDK_Bovine_ntc_6200/compiler/arm-cdcs-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.la'
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove this dependency?

Comment: Have you tried compiler flag -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs? They may be C only, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Compiler or linker flag?

Comment: I've added '-nodefaultlibs' to libsmartrest_la_LDFLAGS but it didn't remove the dependency from the .la file. I want the dependencies cleared just like when I build on a host system.

Comment: For now I'm removing the .la files completely after building so I can build depending libraries, but I find this is more of a hack instead of an actual solution.

Comment: You might get away with using `libsupc++.a` with gcc. Even if you don't use the standard library explicitly, you still need C++ runtime support for things like the exception handling mechanism, static initialization routines, RTTI, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using RTTI based C++ functionality like exceptions or typeof/dynmaic_cast. You can try building with `-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions`. That should remove the dependency or show where you actually have it.

If that doesn't help and you are using GCC 4.5 or newer, try compiling with `-static-libstdc++`.